# Random symmetric walk in two dimensions in c,

Tags: c, srand

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int t=0;
    int s=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;1;i++){
        printf("%d. (%d,%d)\n",i,t,s);
        if(t== 0 && s==0){
            system("pause");
            printf("\n");
            i=0;
        }
        int k= rand()%4;
        if(k==0)t--;
        else if(k==1)t++;
        else if(k==2)s--;
        else s++;
    }
}
```

My code generates random symmetric walk in two dimensions.
It generates a random integer between 0 and 3, and based on that it moves up, down, left or right. There is a maths theorem, that guarantees that the walk ends (reaches (0,0)) in finite steps.

The code works, but when i press enter enough times, i notice that the symmetric walks repeat. For example, first I generate walk of length 206785, and then after 5-6 walks, I again generate walk of length 206785. I guess this is the problem with srand() function, but can someone clarify where the problem lies.

Edit: Oh yes, im trying this on codeblocks.

Comment: "when i press enter enough times," --> Are you saying you run the programs multiple times within the same second?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the small *periodicity* of your C library's implementation of the [Pseudorandom Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) used by *rand*. All PRNGs have a periodicity, i.e. the sequence repeats by necessity. Use a pseudo-random number generator with a larger periodicity. I could search one for you but don't want to spoil the fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

The rand() function generates 32768 different pseudo-random values, and if you call it enough times the sequence will repeat. You can achieve more (apparent) randomness by adding something like this inside your for loop, assuming the loop takes more than 1 millisecond to run.

```
srand(rand() ^ (unsigned)time(NULL));
```

A better alternative would be to replace the rand() by some more advanced random number library such as [boost::random](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_random.html)

Comment: boost::random in a C program? Surely you jest.

Comment: okay sorry, but I'm sure you can find something else.

Comment: " 32768 different pseudo-random values, and if you call it enough times the sequence will repeat." --> The number of "different pseudo-random values" is independent of the generator's sequence length.

Comment: `The rand() function generates 32768 different pseudo-random values` no, `rand()` generates `RAND_MAX + 1` different pseudo-random values and the value of `RAND_MAX` depends on implementation

Answer (score 0):

Calling code multiple time sin the same second (e.g. `time()` has the same value) results in the same output.

Instead of `srand((unsigned)time(NULL))`, code need to include other differentiating data for the initialization.  Perhaps a process ID, counted from a file, microsecond wall time.